# Trying to create a new coded domain and Arcpy is rejecting my domain name

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, error-000732, domains

For some reason I'm getting a "ERROR 000192: Invalid value for Domain Name" in the below script. The domain name is "Road_Class_Types". I can't figure out why it's giving me this error. Why doesn't it like it? What am I missing?

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time). Update foe each new file.
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ROBERT FILES\EXTRACTION WORKING FOLDER"
 
# Set parameters
domName = "Road_Class_Types"
gdb = "ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb"
inFeatures = "ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb\TransportationGroundCrv_AddFieldTest"
inField = "AP030_Road_Class"
fieldName1 = "AP030_Road_Class"
fieldPrecision = 9
fieldAlias = "Road_Class"
fieldLength = 200

# Process: Create the coded value domain
arcpy.CreateDomain_management("ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb", "Road_Class_Types", "Road Class types per LTDS schema", "TEXT", "CODED")

# Store all the domain values in a dictionary with the domain code as the "key" and the domain description as the "value" (domDict[code])
domDict = {"Class 5 Road": "Class 5 Road - Unimproved (ZI016_ROC = 1), Fair Weather (ZI016_WTC = 2), one (1) or two lanes (2) or less, (LTN = 1 or 2, FCO =7", \
           "Class 4 Road": "Class 4 Road - Flexible Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 3), Limited All-weather (ZI016_WTC = 4), one (1) or two lanes (2) or less, (LTN = 2), FCO =7", \
           "Class 1 Highway": "Class 1 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), three lanes (3), (LTN = 3), FCO = 5 or 6", \
           "Class 2 Highway": "Class 2 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), two lanes (2), (LTN = 2), FCO = 5 or 6", \
           "Class 3 Highway": "Class 3 Highway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Undivided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), one (1) or two (2) or less, (LTN = 2), FCO = 7", \
           "Superhighway": "Superhighway - Rigid Pavement (ZI016_ROC = 7), Divided Highway, All Weather (ZI016_WTC = 1), four or more lanes (4), (LTN>=4),FCO = 5 or 6", \
           "noInformation" : "noInformation"}

# Process: Add valid types to the domain
#use a for loop to cycle through all the domain codes in the dictionary
for code in domDict:        
arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(gdb, domName, code, domDict[code])
    
# Process: Constrain the material value of distribution mains
arcpy.AssignDomainToField_management(inFeatures, inField, domName)
```

Comment: Does C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ROBERT FILES\EXTRACTION WORKING FOLDER\ROBERT_WORKING_EXTRACTION.gdb\TransportationGroundCrv_AddFieldTest exist? I would caution you to avoid using paths on C drive in Windows, UAC will stomp on your processes without warning. Also **get rid of the ampersand in your script name** it's just going to cause problems when you least expect it - & is a special character in CMD. Note that the line causing the error is not present in your script sample.

Comment: Thank you--making your suggested changes now. I messed up thought and put the wrong error code at the bottom, it was an old error. The domain name error is the one I'm still getting.

Comment: I removed the ampersand and am still getting the below error:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.8\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 1612, in CreateDomain
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000192: Invalid value for Domain Name
Failed to execute (CreateDomain).

Comment: Does the domain already exist? Try changing domName = "Road_Class_Types" to domName = "RCTypes" and see if you get the same error. You can use ListDomains https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000001z000000 to check for an existing name within the domain objects https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000020000000 - assuming the code hasn't changed significantly from the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the following arcpy commands:

```
arcpy.CreateDomain_management
```

with

```
arcpy.management.CreateDomain
```

and

```
arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management
```

with

```
arcpy.management.AddCodedValueToDomain
```

and

```
arcpy.AssignDomainToField_management
```

with

```
arcpy.management.AssignDomainToField
```

This worked for me.